# Input a string in grep command in python

Tags: python, string, grep

I have a list of strings in python and want to run a recursive grep on each string in the list. Am using the following code,

```
import subprocess as sp 
for python_file in python_files:
    out = sp.getoutput("grep -r python_file . | wc -l")
    print(out)
```

The output I am getting is the grep of the string "python_file". What mistake am I committing and what should I do to correct this??

Comment: `out = sp.getoutput(f"grep -r {python_file} . | wc -l")`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, now its using grep for "{python_file}"

Comment: If that's what it's doing, you missed the crucial `f` before the opening quote.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several issues. The immediate answer to what you seem to be asking was given in a comment, but there are more things to fix here.

If you want to pass in a variable instead of a static string, you have to use some sort of string interpolation.

`grep` already knows how to report how many lines matched; use `grep -c`.  Or just ask Python to count the number of output lines. Trimming off the pipe to `wc -l` allows you to also avoid invoking a shell, which is a good thing; see also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess).

`grep` already knows how to search for multiple expressions. Try passing in the whole list as an input file with `grep -f -`.

```py
import subprocess as sp
out = sp.check_output(
    ["grep", "-r", "-f", "-", "."],
    input="\n".join(python_files), text=True)
print(len(out.splitlines()))
```

If you want to speed up your processing and the patterns are all static strings, try also adding the `-F` option to `grep`.

Of course, all of this is relatively easy to do natively in Python, too.  You should easily be able to find examples with `os.walk()`.

Comment: yeah, some form of `grep -f -` is probably what they really want

Answer (score 0):

Your intent isn't totally clear from the way you've written your question, but the first argument to `grep` is the **pattern** (`python_file` in your example), and the second is the **file(s)** `.` in your example

You could write this in native Python or just use grep directly, which is probably easier than using both!

`grep` args

- `--count` will report just the number of matching lines
- `--file` *Read one or more newline separated patterns from file.* (manpage)

```sh
grep --count --file patterns.txt -r .
```

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path

for pattern in patterns:
    count = 0
    for path_file in Path(".").iterdir():
        with open(path_file) as fh:
            for line in fh:
                if re.match(pattern, line):
                   count += 1
    print(count)
```

NOTE that the behavior in your question would get a separate word count for each pattern, while you may really want a single count

Comment: `glob(".")` will only traverse the current directory, whereas `grep -r` also examines all subdirectories recursively.

Comment: @tripleee ah, it was a rush job after you mashed go on your grep-only answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: It's not hard to fix, but it's also not hard to find existing questions about how to do this properly, and the requirements in the question are rather unclear, so I didn't go this route.